# <string> and True vs. True and <string> in Python

Tags: python, boolean-logic

Why does the Python interpreter return `True` in the first case and `'a'` in the second?

```
>>> 'a' and True
True
>>> True and 'a'
'a'
```

Answer (score 0):

You're calculating bool expression, since it has *and* between, and first element is True (even 'a' is True as well). Python goes to last element in expression and returns it as requested. Based on this try to answer what will result for:

```
>>> False and 'a'

>>> True or 'a'
```